# How to call a python file in aws sagemaker from angular application?

Tags: python, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have created an angular application that takes an image as input, the image is then passed to a python script that performs a neural style transfer and returns the stylized image. I have created the python file and the angular frontend seperately and I'm stuck on the integration. I am using aws sagemaker to run the python script (due to its computation speed) but I have no idea how to call the python script with the image passed to it from angular. Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: dockerize your python script, and use a SageMaker endpoint to host it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a lambda function and expose it using API gateway to be called by your angular app. this lambda in return will call the  Sagemaker function you have

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/call-an-amazon-sagemaker-model-endpoint-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/